# Is it possible that a Service remains after the App which started the Service is deinstalled(!) from device?

Tags: android, service, push-notification

For a better understanding:

Is it possible, that a service that was installed by an app remains on the device even after the app was deinstalled?
I can't seem to find it, but there was a malware that came with a service that showed spam push notifications even after the app was deinstalled. Was this Service a stand alone app that was also installed or a real 'service' that remained?

There are many threads about the question if it remains after an app or another service is stopped. Here I mean really deinstalled from the device.

Thanks in advance!

[edit: typo]

Comment: If you uninstall the application from device, your service will destroy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If service was in different .apk - YES.

If service was in the same .apk - NO.